# Can my employer ask around to other coworkers on where my new job is?

Tags: human-resources, job-change

I put my 2 weeks and did not tell my boss my new job name. Boss is now asking coworkers if they know. Is that okay to do?

Comment: Legally (if so, please ask on Law SE including your jurisdiction)? Ethically (if so, why do you care)? Something else?

Comment: In the US, it's perfectly legal and ok to ask, which is why you should not tell your coworkers where you're going if that's really a concern to you.

Comment: ... or, if you do, tell your cow-orkers that you'd rather that information not go further. If you don't make that request, they have no reason to presume you consider it confidential.

Comment: Note that it's much more likely that they want to stay in touch and possibly use you as a contact point for negotiations with that company than that they have any more evil purpose. I'm not convinced this is worth worrying about.

Comment: There are countries where the old job and the new job have to know each other, for buerocratic legal reasons. So the better question to answer yourself might be " why do you want it to be a secret?".

Answer (score 1):

You asked two questions here: "Can my boss?" Yes, unless your country has some law against it, but I've never heard of that. "Is that okay?" Arguably no, that's sort of a weird thing to do. But since your boss is, be careful who you share that information with.

That said, if you're concerned about your boss contacting your new employer and trying to slander you, you may not have to worry too much depending on where you live. In many countries, such as the United States and UK, that's legally perilous to the point where companies will have policies to not give information on former employees for references beyond "they worked here from this date to this date". You'll have to do research on if that's true for your specific country, though.

Comment: "that's legally perilous to the point where companies will have policies to not give information on former employees for references" This depends massively on country and industry.

Comment: Good point, I'll clarify. Thanks!